# How to make a .php act like index.php when there's no index.php?

Tags: php, content-management-system, installation

Theoretically: You have a cms and an install.php to that. You want to run the install.php first, and at the end of the steps that would generate and save an index.php before it's deleting itself.

The steps of the install.php:

1. lincense agreement
2. php,mysql version check
3. saving mysql.php
4. saving index.php, deleting install.php, header location:index.php

My question is: How to run install.php automatically when you go to your web page? (Like wordpress' famous 5-minute installation.)

I know that i shouldn't use an installer like this, but it's my homework.

Comment: I don't know how to start :S Should I rename it? Is there an other name in every server for the default starting page that i can use beside index.php?

Comment: it is the job of the web server to fill in the page name if there is none supplied. you need to check there. BTW which web server are you using?

Comment: It's a cms. Everybody can install it everywhere (the requirements are php5+, mysql extension, session.auto_start disabled, gd extension,writable config.php) so the server I use is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .htaccess , write-

```
DirectoryIndex install.php index3.php index4.php default.htm
```

where install.php index3.php index4.php default.htm are general other pages of your directive, by default index2.php gets loaded, if its not present index3.php gets loaded and so on.

Comment: my pleasure! :) You can accept my answer if it worked for you.